# Найти все файлы по расширению и выполнить с ними действие через bat

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Всем привет.
Делю конвертацию файла через bat

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to docx  "один.doc"
```

Но файлов в папке очень много и каждый раз вписывать "один.doc","два.doc","три.doc" сильно напрягает
Как найти все файлы по расширению .doc , подставив название файла в код выше и выполнить его.
Все файлы лежат в одной папке.

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-то так наверное.
Может кому пригодиться.

```
@echo off 
chcp 1251
For /R  %%i in (*.doc) Do ("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to docx  "%%i")
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: `*.doc`, должно сработать